# Does Magento support managing consumers on multi-nodes? If it supports, what is the best way to run consumers on multi-nodes?

Tags: magento-cron, consumers

**Prerequisites**

I uses OSS Magento 2.4.5-p1.
I understand Magento provides some consumers for asynchronous and bulk process and cousumers are managed and launched by magento cron as shown in ref.1.
I also understand there is ‘multiple_processes’ option in env.php and ‘multi-process’ in ‘bin/magento consumer:start’ command. It works and I can run multi consumers on a single-node by magento cron.

As for magento cron, I understand magento docs ref.2 says “In a multi-node system, crontab can run on only one node. This applies to you only if you set up more than one webnode for reasons related to performance or scalability.”

**What I want to do**

I would like to manage and run consumers on multi-nodes for parallel processing. Does Magento support managing consumers on multi-nodes(multi server or multi container)? If it supports, what is the best way to manage and run consumers on multi-nodes? I would like to know the official opinion on Magento.

**What I checked**

I tried to set magento cron command: `bin/magento cron:run --consumers` in crontab on multi-node and issued messages to the queue for 'async.operations.all'. It turned out consumers were launched only on a single-node when messages entered in the queue. I understand this is because lockManager checks the lock in line 133 in ‘module-message-queue/Model/Cron/ConsumersRunner.php’.
[image: ConsumersRunner.php line133]

**Reference**

1. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/message-queues/manage-message-queues.html
2. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/configure-cron-jobs.html